# Ringtones download

Tags: iphone, download

I'm new to iphone. I have question please answer to it..
I have some ringtones i want to place in a my xcode and people who want it they able to download from my application.
How it is possible.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understand you have some audio files included in your xcode bundle(project) and now you want to provide option to the users as a downloading for price or free. If my understanding or guess is exactly correct, you defiantly follow below link  [In-app-purchase](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-in-app-purchases/). All the best